# Unexplained vertical space between some bib entries?

Tags: bibliographies, pdftex, natbib, apa6

I'm using the APA6 package with natbib, and I noticed that some of my bib entries have a vertical space. I think it has to do with there being a particularly long "word" at the end of an entry (e.g., a URL or doi).

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

And here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}    

\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{Author Name}
\affiliation{Author Affiliation}
\abstract{Abstract}

\begin{document}

\citep{Baron2004,Foster1965a,eibach2006free,ElectionsCanada,trivers2000elements,VonNeumann1944,VanLange1999b,VanLange1997a}

\urlstyle{same}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Here are the bib entries:

```
@article{trivers2000elements,
author = {Trivers, Robert},
doi = {10.1111/j.1749-6632.2000.tb06619.x},
journal = {Annals of the New York Academy of Sciences},
number = {1},
pages = {114--131},
publisher = {Wiley Online Library},
title = {{The elements of a scientific theory of self-deception}},
volume = {907},
year = {2000}
}

@misc{ElectionsCanada,
author = {{Elections Canada}},
title = {{Voter turnout at federal elections and referendums}},
url = {http://www.elections.ca/content.aspx?section=ele\&dir=turn\&document=index\&lang=e},
year = {2013}
}

@article{Baron2004,
author = {Baron, Jonathan and Kemp, Simon},
doi = {10.1016/S0167-4870(03)00064-3},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Baron, Kemp - 2004 - Support for trade restrictions, attitudes, and understanding of comparative advantage.pdf:pdf},
issn = {01674870},
journal = {Journal of Economic Psychology},
month = oct,
number = {5},
pages = {565--580},
title = {{Support for trade restrictions, attitudes, and understanding of comparative advantage}},
volume = {25},
year = {2004}
}

@article{eibach2006free,
  title={Free at last? Social dominance, loss aversion, and White and Black Americans' differing assessments of racial progress.},
  author={Eibach, Richard P and Keegan, Thomas},
  journal={Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
  volume={90},
  number={3},
  pages={453},
  year={2006},
  publisher={American Psychological Association}
}

@book{VonNeumann1944,
address = {Princeton},
author = {{Von Neumann}, J and Morgenstern, O},
chapter = {1},
isbn = {0691003629},
issn = {00280836},
publisher = {Princeton University Press},
series = {Princeton Classic Editions},
title = {{Theory of games and economic behavior}},
year = {1944}
}

@article{VanLange1997a,
author = {{Van Lange}, P.A.M. and {De Bruin}, E. and Otten, W and Joireman, J.A.},
doi = {10.1037//0022-3514.73.4.733},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Van Lange et al. - 1997 - Development of prosocial, individualistic, and competitive orientations theory and preliminary evidence.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0022-3514},
journal = {Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
mendeley-groups = {OLD/Fall 2012/Loosely Sorted/PhD/Thesis/Prosocial,OLD/Fall 2012/Loosely Sorted/PhD/Thesis/Prosocial/Measurement,social value orientation,Thesis BibteX},
month = oct,
number = {4},
pages = {733},
publisher = {American Psychological Association},
title = {{Development of prosocial, individualistic, and competitive orientations: theory and preliminary evidence.}},
volume = {73},
year = {1997}
}

@article{VanLange1999b,
author = {{Van Lange}, P.A.M.},
doi = {10.1037//0022-3514.77.2.337},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Van Lange - 1999 - The pursuit of joint outcomes and equality in outcomes An integrative model of social value orientation(2).pdf:pdf},
issn = {0022-3514},
journal = {Journal of Personality and Social Psychology},
number = {2},
pages = {337--349},
title = {{The pursuit of joint outcomes and equality in outcomes: An integrative model of social value orientation}},
volume = {77},
year = {1999}
}

@article{Foster1965a,
author = {Foster, GM},
doi = {10.1525/aa.1965.67.2.02a00010},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Tyler/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Foster - 1965 - Peasant society and the image of limited good.pdf:pdf},
journal = {American Anthropologist},
number = {2},
pages = {293--315},
title = {{Peasant society and the image of limited good}},
volume = {67},
year = {1965}
}
```

Can I tell it to add a line-break or something?

Comment: It's surely possible that the “long words” have something to do with this; could you please add a couple of the problematic bib entries so we can play with them?

Comment: @egreg -- Whoops, that would help! Bib entries added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apacite.sty` package that's loaded by class wrongly defines `\PrintBackRefs` in case back references are not wanted.

Indeed, it defines it to be the same as `\@gobble`, but the end of an entry in the generated `.bbl` file is like

```
\APACjournalVolNumPages{Journal of Economic Psychology}{25}{5}{565--580}.
\newblock
\begin{APACrefDOI} \doi{10.1016/S0167-4870(03)00064-3} \end{APACrefDOI}
\PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib}
```

This is the problem: *two* spaces are seen here, from the two final end-of-lines and the `\par` automatically supplied only removes one. Such a space can “go to the next line” if the last word ends very near to the right edge, so creating a new line.

You can fix the issue by adding

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{backref}{}{\renewcommand{\PrintBackRefs}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}}%
}
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble. This is the standard method used in LaTeX for making a command *transparent* if it should do nothing and can be preceded by a space.

Full code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}    

%%% fix the issue in apacite.sty
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{backref}{}{\renewcommand{\PrintBackRefs}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}}%
}
\makeatother


\title{Title}
\shorttitle{Short Title}
\author{Author Name}
\affiliation{Author Affiliation}
\abstract{Abstract}

\begin{document}

\citep{Baron2004,Foster1965a,eibach2006free,ElectionsCanada,trivers2000elements,VonNeumann1944,VanLange1999b,VanLange1997a}

\urlstyle{same}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]